# Flex 4: Flash Player 11 SWZ files caching

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, mxml, flash

I am usig the **Flex 4.1** to create my Application, and to reduce the size of the application.swf **I sat the framework linkage to RSL**, which produce a small swf file.
     and as what I read about the RSL the client will download the SWZ files at first time and cached them to be used, **but I faced an issue with Flash Player 11 where the        swz files did not get cached and the application download them each time**. so please advice about it, and is this related to the version of the Flash Player?

```
 these are the files Names textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz,textLayout.swc,framework_4.1.0.16076.swz,fra mework.swc
  here is how I added the links in the flex-config.xml.

 ===================================================================== ==========

<runtime-shared-library-path>
                <path-element>libs/textLayout.swc</path-element>
                <rsl-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/Libs/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
                <rsl-url>textLayout_1.1.0.604.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
      </runtime-shared-library-path>

<!-- OSMF SWC -->
<runtime-shared-library-path>
                <path-element>libs/osmf.swc</path-element>
                <rsl-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/Libs/osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
                <rsl-url>osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
      </runtime-shared-library-path>

<!-- Framework SWC -->
      <runtime-shared-library-path>
                <path-element>libs/framework.swc</path-element>
                <rsl-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/Libs/framework_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
                <rsl-url>framework_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
      </runtime-shared-library-path>

<!-- Spark SWC-->
         <runtime-shared-library-path>
                <path-element>libs/spark.swc</path-element>
                <rsl-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/Libs/spark_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
                <rsl-url>spark_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
      </runtime-shared-library-path>

<!-- Sparkskins SWC-->
         <runtime-shared-library-path>
                <path-element>libs/sparkskins.swc</path-element>
                <rsl-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/Libs/sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
                <rsl-url>sparkskins_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
      </runtime-shared-library-path>

      <!-- RPC SWC -->
      <runtime-shared-library-path>
                <path-element>libs/rpc.swc</path-element>
                <rsl-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/Libs/rpc_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url>https://ibill.mobily.com.sa/crossdomain.xml</policy-file-url>
                <rsl-url>rpc_4.1.0.16076.swz</rsl-url>
                <policy-file-url></policy-file-url>
      </runtime-shared-library-path>
```

=================================================

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you notice, that RSLs are not cached?

Comment: I notice you changed the framework SWZs to a HTTPS location. Not sure if this is any help to you, but I had a similar issue a few days ago when I tried enabling SSL with an EV certificate for our application. Chrome didn't show the expected EV-Status (green address bar) because Flashplayer kept downloading the SWZs from HTTP URLs, even though I replaced the failover URLs with HTTPS URLs in our build script. Eventually I removed the failover SWFs completely.

Comment: there is nothing related to the HTTPS becuase I test it by http. and I how I checked that the cache not working, simply by clear the Flash player cache. so please advice. @ Timofei Davydik